# Conditional sorting of a data.table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, data-wrangling

I have very large `data.table` that I want to trim down in this fashion:

1. Only one unique id
2. If there is any other data than "X" in the same log, that other should stay
3. If only X, then the first X should stay
4. If there is more than one other than "X", then all those should stay, separated by commas, but not the "X".

Sample dataset:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(
    id=c(1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5),
    log=c(11,11,11,12,12,12,12,12,13,13),
    art=c("X", "Y", "X", "X", "X", "Z", "X", "Y","X", "X")
  )
dt
id log art
1:  1  11   X
2:  1  11   Y
3:  2  11   X
4:  3  12   X
5:  3  12   X
6:  4  12   Z
7:  4  12   X
8:  4  12   Y
9:  5  13   X
10: 5  13   X
```

Required output:

```
 id    log  art    
  1     11   Y    
  2     11   Y
  3     12   Z,Y
  4     12   Z,Y
  5     13   X
```

Comment: id = 3 and log = 12 does not contain `Z` or `Y`, yet it is in your expected output. Also could you please format your code?

Comment: Well, maybe it wasnt entirely clear - if there is just one Y in log 12, all log 12's should be Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method, though there maybe a more efficient approach.

```
unique(dt[,.(id, log)])[dt[, .(art=if(.N == 1 | all(art == "X"))
                                      art[1] else toString(unique(art[art != "X"]))),
                           by=log], on="log"]
```

which returns

```
   id log  art
1:  1  11    Y
2:  2  11    Y
3:  3  12 Z, Y
4:  4  12 Z, Y
5:  5  13    X
```

perform a left join of the desired values of art by each log onto the unique pairs of ID and log. This assumes that no ID spans two logs, which is the case in the example.

Comment: Sorry, but I didnt make myself clear. All in art in each level of log should be the same.

Comment: @JeppeOlsen Ah. I see what you mean. I have adjusted the code to produce the outcome you mention.

Comment: I came across one more thing - if there were more columns in my dataset, how could i keep those?

Comment: I suppose this would depend on what you want to do with them and what they look like. If the goal is the same as what you wanted to do with art, then you could perform an `lapply` on `.SD` with `.SDcols` selecting the columns. On the other hand, if they are the same values within ID, then you can place them in the `unique` call at the beginning. On the third hand, if you want to calculate some function, say the `sum` of numeric variables, then it would probably warrant an additional join. If the first or the third, it would probably be worth asking a separate question if this isn't clear.

Answer (score 2):

We can try

```
dt[,  .(art = if(all(art=="X")) "X" else 
     toString(unique(art[art != "X"]))), .(id, logbld = log)]
#    id logbld  art
#1:  1     11    Y
#2:  2     11    X
#3:  3     12    X
#4:  4     12 Z, Y
#5:  5     13    X
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to try this with ***`dplyr`***:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
   dat <- setDT(dt %>% group_by(id) %>% 
                       unique() %>% 
                       summarise(bldlog = mean(log),
                                 art = gsub("X,|,X", "",paste(art, collapse = ","))))


dat

#    id bldlog art 
# 1:  1     11   Y 
# 2:  2     11   X 
# 3:  3     12   X 
# 4:  4     12 Z,Y 
# 5:  5     13   X
```

Comment: I don't think `setDT` is designed to play nice with tibbledy-dos, unless hadley has implemented a setDT.tibbledy method somewhere. For safety/sanity, I'd just use `data.table()` or `as.data.table()`.

Comment: @Frank Correct, it is not designed for them. But have you ever had a problem with using `setDT` on a `tibble`?

Comment: I would never do it, but maybe I'm overcautious. Btw, if you load dtplyr, I guess `tbl_dt` and `data.table` will both be in the `class` vector already, so there's no need to `setDT`

Comment: @Frank Tbh this is the first time I did this and I don't think I will end up using it again. p.s. Being cautious is good. Thanks for pointing this out.